# MongoDB repair & drop deleted databases?

Tags: mongodb

I foolishly deleted a number of old, unused database directories on disk. Now MongoDB won't start. I tried repairing, but the repair fails with this error:

```
2020-05-05T13:33:19.367+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase deleted_database
2020-05-05T13:33:19.367+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection deleted_database.SDN
2020-05-05T13:33:19.368+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1588685599:368535][2388:0x7f760c6d6140], file:deleted_database/collection/44858-8988382436374591788.wt, WT_SESSION.verify: /mnt/disks/data1/mongodb//deleted_database/collection/44858-8988382436374591788.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2020-05-05T13:33:19.368+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify failed on uri table:deleted_database/collection/44858-8988382436374591788. Running a salvage operation.
2020-05-05T13:33:19.368+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1588685599:368767][2388:0x7f760c6d6140], file:deleted_database/collection/44858-8988382436374591788.wt, WT_SESSION.salvage: /mnt/disks/data1/mongodb//deleted_database/collection/44858-8988382436374591788.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2020-05-05T13:33:19.368+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure rs.get() src/mongo/db/catalog/database_impl.cpp 226
2020-05-05T13:33:19.368+0000 F -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after invariant() failure
```

Where `deleted_database` is one of the databases I deleted.

I don't need to recover this data. Is there a way to get MongoDB to forget about these databases?